# I was a rapporteur of the main session of an intergovernmental forum, should I add the final report as a publication in my CV?

Tags: publications, citations, conference, cv

I was an intern at an intergovernmental organization, during an international forum I reported the first and main panel, should I add the final report in my CV as a publication? 
The final report's bibliography has: the organization's name, date, forum name. Within the report there is the list of the editors and then the rapporteurs were my name is listed. However, as I did not participate to edit the report I hesitate to add it. What do you think?

Comment: Is this CV for academic jobs or for some other purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You should ask the organization specifically what is appropriate. It might be fine, but I know of other such international collaborations in which it is specifically forbidden to claim authorship. The work is attributed to the committee as a whole, by name.

An additional reason for not doing this is the question as to whether it is a creative work on your part. I can't judge, of course, but it seems unlikely.

You can, of course, include your participation elsewhere in the CV.

Comment: Why has someone downvoted this excellent answer? I draw attention to @Buffy's final sentence: being a rapporteur is an important accomplishment in its own right whether or not you are permitted to claim authorship of the resulting document. In my earlier career I was the principal author of numerous reports which, for legal reasons, had to be attributed to another legal person. Later I was such a legal person and large numbers of reports written by my staff are legally mine, although I did not necessarily contribute much to them.

Comment: My CV would certainly mention what I did in these jobs but I could not claim actual authorship of reports not bearing my name, or take credit for those that did  when I was merely the titular author for legal purposes.

Comment: @JeremyC, people vote for their own reasons, of course. Sometimes a single word is enough. I'm comfortable with the answer, of course.